# Immutability: property of variable, value, or API?

Tags: programming-languages, immutability, language-design

I'm working on designing a gradually typed language as a personal project and I'm stuck at a particular design decision regarding immutability.

Talking about this in a language agnostic (and probably crude) way, I say there are two things that could be immutable or constant: the variable binding and the value itself.

The variable binding being constant is like `const` in Javascript or `final` in Java, where the variable cannot be reassigned. The value itself being immutable is like `const` in C++ or `Object.freeze()` in Javascript.

The question I'm having is, in the case of immutable values (not bindings) what should immutability be a property of?

The value/object itself in Javascript's `Object.freeze`?

```
var point = {x: 10};
var frozenPoint = Object.freeze(point);
```

or part of the type as in C++?

```
const Point p(10);
```

or as the variable binding as in Rust?

```
let p = Point { x: 10 };
// vs let mut p = Point { x: 10 };
```

or as part of the API of a library? Facebook's Immutable.js, Google's Guava library for Java (`ImmutableList` class), etc.

I understand that there's probably no "correct" answer for this, so what I'm really looking for is a comparison of the philosophies and motivations for these approaches.

Answer (score 1):

There is a correct answer, but it is very different than what you expect.

The best is to not have mutability at all. In other words : the language should be purely functional. There is no reason to have mutability in a language with garbage collection. Haskell is a proof of this.

Comment: I understand this viewpoint, but I can't agree that it is the "correct answer". Surely it's a subjective opinion that pure immutability is the "best" way to do things. The target audience I'm imagining would probably prefer a way to control mutability and hence I'm looking for a way to provide that control elegantly and "correctly".

Comment: Modern purely functional languages give the possibility to have mutations, and also very elegant and bug-free ways to control them. It is just done at a higher level than the core language semantics. Therefore the saying "Haskell is the best imperative language.".

Comment: I understand the audience reasoning, but i disagree with it. Instead of giving the imperative audience yet another language, they should be encouraged to move to purely functional programming.

Comment: Ah, well, it seems like we have reached an impasse then.